# How to display options of custom attribute product magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, attribute-options

I have created a **custom attribute** for product and I can add options dynamically as well. But the problem now I'm facing is that I want to display just the option relative to the current product, so when I proceed to create the configuration according to this attribute I will just find the options relative to this product so how to do that please and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not understand what you want trying to achieve?

Comment: in fact i want to delete dupplicated options for this attribute of configuration and i want when accessing a product X to see in this attribute just the value options related to this product so how to do that